# Frechet derivative of an homogeneous function

Tags: frechet-derivative, fixed-points

Let be $ f:X\to X$ a homogeneous function of degree 1 definied on a real Banach space $X$ and suppose that exists $u\in X$ such that $f(u)=u$. Let be $L$ the Frechet derivative of $f$ at $u$, i.e. $L=f'(u)$. I would like to prove that $Lu=u$. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$
\lambda u = \lambda f(u) = (1 + \lambda)f(u) - f(u) =
f(u + \lambda u) - f(u) = L(\lambda u) + o(\lambda u) =
\lambda L(u) + o(\lambda).
$$
Now, divide by $\lambda$ and take $\lambda\to 0$.

EDIT: an easy generalization: $f$ homogeneous of degree 1 and $f(u) = v\implies f'(u)u = v$:
$$
\lambda v = \lambda f(u) = (1 + \lambda)f(u) - f(u) =
f(u + \lambda u) - f(u) = L(\lambda u) + o(\lambda u) =
\lambda L(u) + o(\lambda).
$$
And link about the [o-notation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)